# ASP.net MVC - Using Dropdown Lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The system is for managing movie rentals. A user can Manage Customers, Add Manage Movies, and manage Rentals.

Here are my models:

Customers Model

```
namespace u1265196_MovieRentals.Models
{
    public class Customers
    {


        [Display(Name = "Customer ID")]
        [Key]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Postcode")]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Phone No")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Rentals> Rentals { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Movies Model:

```
namespace u1265196_MovieRentals.Models
{
    public class Movies
    {
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Director { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Length of film")]
        public string Length { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int AgeRating { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Rentals> Rentals { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Rentals Model:

```
namespace u1265196_MovieRentals.Models
{
    public class Rentals
    {
        [Key]
        public int RentalID { get; set; }

        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateRented { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
        public virtual Customers Customers { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("MovieID")]
        public virtual Movies Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my Rentals View i want to display a dropdown list containing all Customers First + Last Names. i also want to display a dropdown list containing all Movie Titles.

When a user selects a customer and movie from the dropdown lists and clicks save, i want the relevant ID's of the selected customer and selected movie to be stored in the Rentals Table.

How do i go about doing this?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for AddRental within my RentalsController:

```
 // GET: Rentals/Create


        public ActionResult AddRental()
        {

            var vm = new RentMovieVm();
            vm.Customers = CustomerDataAccess.GetAllCustomers().Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.Id.ToString(), Text = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName }).ToList();
            vm.Movies = MoviesDataAccess.GetAllMovies().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.Title }).ToList();
            return View(vm);
        }

        // POST: Rentals/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddRental(RentMovieVm model)
        {
            var movieID = model.MovieID;
            var customerID = model.CustomerID;


            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    RentalsDataAccess RentalsDA = new RentalsDataAccess();

                    if (RentalsDA.AddRental(model))
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "Rental added successfully";
                    }
                }
                return View();
            }
            catch

            {
                return View();

            }
        }
```

Here is the code AddRental within my RentalsDataAccess Class:

```
 public bool AddRental(RentMovieVm obj)
        {

            connection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("AddNewRental", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", obj.CustomerID);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieID", obj.MovieID);



            con.Open();
            int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (i >= 1)
            {

                return true;

            }
            else
            {

                return false;
            }


        }
```

**Edit2**

CustomersDataAccess:

```
public List<Customers> GetAllCustomers()


        {
            connection();
            List<Customers> CustomerList = new List<Customers>();


            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("GetCustomers", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                CustomerList.Add(

                    new Customers
                    {

                        CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CustomerID"]),
                        FirstName = Convert.ToString(dr["FirstName"]),
                        LastName = Convert.ToString(dr["LastName"]),


                    }


                    );

            }

            return CustomerList;


        }
```

Comment: Your question may be too broad. Can you show us any attempts? Razor has some pretty straight-forward ways of using dropdown lists. If you're looking for a tutorial, this might not be the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view model SPECIFIC to this view.

```
public class RentMovieVm
{
   public List<SelectListItem> Customers { set; get;}
   public List<SelectListItem> Movies { set; get;}

   public int CustomerId { set; get;}
   public int MovieId { set; get;}
}
```

Now in your GET action, create an object of this, populate the `Customers` and `Movies` properties with data from your tables.

```
public ActionResult Rent()
{  
  var vm = new RentMovieVm();
  vm.Customers= dbContext.Customers.Select(s=> new SelectListItem { 
                                             Value =s.CustomerId.ToString(),
                                             Text= s.FirstName+" "+ s.LastName }).ToList();
  vm.Movies= dbContext.Movies.Select(x=> new SelectListItem { 
                                               Value =x.MovieId.ToString(),
                                               Text= x.Title }).ToList();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now your view will be strongly typed to this view model

```
@model RentMovieVm
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
  <label> Select a customer </label>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.CustomerId, Model.Customers)
  <label> Select a movie </label>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.MovieId, Model.Movies)

  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now in your HttpPost action method, you can use the same `RentMovieVm` class as the parameter so model binder will be able to map the posted form data to properties of this class's object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Rent(RentMovieVm model)
{
  var movieId = model.MovieId;
  var customerId = model.CustomreId;
  // to do  : Save this to your Rental Table
  // to do : Return something ( redirect to success page)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Does this only work when using the Entity Framework? I'm not using the entity framework. so far I have used stored procedures to create, edit, and delete Movies and Customers.

Comment: No. The basic concept of rendering dropdown is same. If you are not using EF, Update the `Rent()` GET action method to get data from your other data access method instead of using `dbContext.Customers`. Ex: `yourDataAccessClass.GetCustomers().Select(// existing code)` where `GetCustomers` return a collection of  `Customer`

Comment: Thanks for that. I am still getting an error though. i have added my RentalsDataAccessClass above and also my RentalsController. Could you please take a look and tell me where i might be going wrong? Thanks

Comment: "An Object Reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CustomerDataAccess.GetAllCustomers()" The same for MoviesDataAccess.GetAllMovies()

Comment: is `CustomerDataAccess` a non nullable object ? Put visual studio breakpoint and inspect your variable.

Comment: The error is in my RentalsController at this point:                              vm.Customers = **CustomerDataAccess.GetAllCustomers**().Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.Id.ToString(), Text = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName }).ToList();

Comment: put that line to 2 statements. `var customers=CustomerDataAccess.GetAllCustomers(); vm.Customers=customers.Select(..` and put breakpoint and see which line is failing. My guess is the `CustomerDataAccess` is NULL or you are accessing some null object inside your `GetAllCustomers` method.

Comment: Yes, It's showing an error on this line: var Customers = CustomerDataAccess.GetAllCustomers()

Comment: So you need to find out why it is crashing. put a breakpoint and inspect variable values before executing.

Comment: Could the problem possibly be with the GetAllCustomers method in my CustomersDataAccess class? I have added the code above. Could you please take a look? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you put a breakpoint in that method and check each lines.

Comment: Sorry, i dont know if i made it clear? My project doesn't even build due to the following build error:" An Object Reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CustomerDataAccess.GetAllCustomers()'"